# Why JSP pages often use ! in the url?

Tags: jsp

Like:

http://forums.adobe.com/post!input.jspa?container=2065&containerType=14

Is there any trick in `JSP` that cause `!` so often used in the url?

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to JSP. This is specific to the server side controller/framework used. The Adobe forums use [Jive forum software](http://www.jivesoftware.com/) whose controller apparently manually parses URL's like that. It just get printed like that in HTML `<form>` element of the JSP, probably with the intent to pass some extra information along the HTTP POST request.

You could easily code your controller to do the same. However if it was me, I wouldn't do it that way.